# .htaccess redirect URLs with specific path to 404 and exclude some URLs with the same path as exception

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, regex-lookarounds

I have an application on Codeigniter(3.1.11). Basically, I want a 404 redirect of URLs which have `dashboard` in URI. Like these:

```
dashboard/foo/bar
dashboard/foo-2/bar-2
dashboard/something
...
```

Also, I want to keep some exceptions in redirect rule so, some of the specific URLs which have `dashboard` as path URI should be excluded from this redirect. Let's say I want to exclude some URLs like:

```
dashboard/new-foo/new-bar
dashboard/one-thing/abc
dashboard/another-thing/xyz
```

I have given a few tries but the exclude rule is not working. It redirects all URLs to 404. This is what I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(dashboard/new-foo/new-bar) [NC]  # Exclude this url (this condition is not working)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dashboard/$1 [R=404,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in a single rule with negative lookahead conditions like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^dashboard(?!/new-foo/new-bar|/one-thing/abc|/another-thing/xyz) - [R=404,NC,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank You! It worked like charm. Only thing not working is path with `/dashboard` only. How can I include `/dashboard` path to also redirect to 404?

Comment: Thank You! Nearly there! It redirects `/home/` to 404 but `/home` is still not redirecting.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, I mean `dashboard`. Please read `home` as `dashboard`

Comment: My bad! There was a dot after parenthesis. Removed it and it worked wonders. Thank You very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not expert with htaccess but I am pretty sure you need 2 RewriteCond lines, one to include all the dashboard urls and then the second to exclude the new ones. Each RewriteCond is implicitly joined with an "AND" so if you have many different patterns to exclude and you need a 3rd RewriteCode then you will need to join the 3rd with an "OR" on the 2nd condition.

e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dashboard/(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dashboard/new-(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 404-page/$1 [R=404,L]
```

There are a couple of other things I'd like to mention: 1) Your RewriteRule redirects back to a /dashboard URL so you could possibly end up in a continuous look here. 2) You don't need to turn on Rewrite engine twice, once at the top is enough.

If the rewrite rules in htaccess are getting complicated then perhaps you could use your index.php file to handle it (or some other method within Codeigniter).